# Number of solutions of the linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

There are two positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $a \mod b$ is not zero.

We find a value $n=\lfloor a/b \rfloor+1$ where $\lfloor .\rfloor$ is the block function.

We are supposed to find the number of solutions of the following equation:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+....x_n=a;\text{ where }1\le x_i \le b \text{ and } 1 \le i \le n.$$

**Example:**

Given: $a=7;b=3$. We get $n =\lfloor a/b \rfloor + 1 = \lfloor 7/3 \rfloor +1 =2+1=3.$

Thus, we need to find the number of solutions of the following equation:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3=7; \text{ where } 1 \le x_i \le 3 \text{ and } 1\le i\le 3.$$

This equation has 6 solutions:

$$x_1=1;x_2=3;x_3=3.$$
$$x_1=3;x_2=1;x_3=3.$$
$$x_1=3;x_2=3;x_3=1.$$
$$x_1=2;x_2=2;x_3=3.$$
$$x_1=2;x_2=3;x_3=2.$$
$$x_1=3;x_2=2;x_3=2.$$

Hence for $a=7;b=3$, the answer is $6$.

I could find this manually because the values of $a$ and $b$ are small. But for large values of $a$ and $b$ in the order of 100s or 1000s, I need to generalise this.